# How to find the xth greatest element in an array of integers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to create a function that finds the xth greatest element in an array. The code below works great if all integers are positive but messes up once a negative number is in the array. For example:

When calling the function with fun([-10,-25,-47,-36,0], 1). The output should be 0 but it gives -47.

How can I make this function work for both positive and negative numbers?

```
const fun = (x, y) => {
    let sorted = x.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a-b;
    });

    let el = x[y -1];

    console.log(el);    
}
```

x being the array of integers and y being the xth greatest element

Comment: Please demonstrate with an example that it doesn't work for some numbers.

Comment: Can you add some additional explanation on this part: _"but messes up once a negative number is in the array"_ - best with a [mcve] including examples for in- and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort the numbers in descending order, you should use `b - a` (second element minus first element).

This allows you to grab the greatest number in the array, like this:

```js
const greatest = (x, y) => {
    // After this call, the array `x` will be sorted
    x.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b - a;
    });

    let el = x[y - 1];
    console.log(el);
    
    return el;  
}

// First greatest number among those in the array

greatest([1, 3, 5], 1); // excepted: 5
greatest([30, 5, 11], 1); // excepted: 30
greatest([-3, -19, -11], 1); // excepted: -3
greatest([1000000, 999999, -1000000], 1); // excepted: 1000000
greatest([Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 0, 10000 * 10000 * 10000], 1); // excepted: Infinity
greatest([Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, 0, -10000 * 10000 * 10000], 1); // excepted: 0
greatest([Number.NaN, Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY], 1); // excepted: NaN
```

Comment: If this answer was useful, please consider **checking the box near the answer** to mark the question as solved.